# Как использовать инстансинг для рендера объектов с различными текстурами в OpenGl?

Tags: разработка-игр, opengl, графика, glsl

Пытаюсь оптимизировать отрисовку большого количества объектов (делаю майнкрафт). Как можно догадаться объекты - кубы, у всех одинаковые VAO. Я вроде понимаю как использовать инстансинг для рендера с различными матрицами, но как добавить к этому различные текстуры не понимаю. Есть идея, объединять объекты с одинаковыми текстурами в группы, делать байнд текстуры, рендерить инстансингом, а потом заново проходится по массиву и так пока не будут отрендерины все блоки, но я не уверен в эффективности такого подхода. Подскажите как можно это осуществить или как это обычно реализуется.

Comment: Вопрос слишком широк. Оптимальным решением видится группировка по блокам в один VAO, например 16х16х16 кубов (вероятно с отсечением невидимой геометрии). Если меняется кубик - генерите весь VAO заново. Если кубы меняются часто, а генерить долго - уменьшаете размер блока, например до 8х8х8. Примерно так ..

Comment: @Kromster Хорошо спасибо, а как вы бы предложили решить проблему с текстурами? Если вам интересна конкретика: хотелось бы добиться результата в проходе по трёхмерному массиву байт (некая часть ладшафта игры) размером в 150 * 150 * 50 = 1 125 000 объектов за один кадр. Также нужно отнять то что многие из этих байт = 0 (блока нет) и чтото frustum scaling отсечёт (но это тоже + нагрузка, но небольшая), того объектов под 200 000. И мне видется только прохождение по этому массиву ладшафта несколько раз, чтобы собирать такие группы как вы говорите, только с одинаковыми текстурами.

Comment: Как вы считаете, хороший ли это вариант? При том что такие VAO нужно будет создавать при каждом изменении в ландшафте, потому что ровные кубы 16x16x16 создать не получится изза группировки по текстурам. Мне чтото кажется что это не лучшее что можно сделать или я скорее чтото не понимаю, потому что на сколько я знаю в оригенальной игре примерно так это и работает.

Comment: Текстура должна быть одна, VAO с кубами не нужен, достаточно одной точки на куб, инстансинг не нужен.